# I have a Pi 2 model b v2 as 2nd monitor

Tags: pi-2

I have a Pi 2 model b v2...I bought a small lcd screen and connected via the pins. I have rasbian on there it works fine. Now, can I use that unit as a second monitor for my desktop pc??

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Do you mean using the Pi for remote access?

Answer (score 1):

While your Raspberry Pi is connected to the display, **NO.**
Unless you are doing a remote desktop, then again that is one display.

If your Raspberry Pi is not connected to the display, **YES, but with some setup.**

You will need to have:

- A graphics card that supports multi displays. (On your PC.)
- Correct Cables (That hook up to the display and to your Desktop's graphics card.)
- Proper Graphics Card Drivers (You can find the right drivers with [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/))